# Make dropzone.js do a raw upload

Tags: rest, dropzone.js

I like to use dropzone.js for file upload to a REST-like server. While dropzone.js can switch the request method to `PUT`, it still sends something like a mulitpart file upload. My server expects raw data as body for the a single ressource `PUT` method, so the files uploaded will have multipart seperators included.

How can I tell dropzone.js to put the raw data into the request body, no more no less?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this answer that I wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38734015/3746828

Add below options, then working.

```
myDropzone.options.sending = function(file, xhr) {
  var _send = xhr.send;
  xhr.send = function() {
    _send.call(xhr, file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is another method that patches xhr with a params function passed in as an option to Dropzone. This method will also work for chunked files. The chunked execution path below also adds the headers required for a resumable file upload using the OneDrive API as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online

```js
const CHUNK_SIZE=10485760 //10MiB

Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
    method: "put",
    headers: {
        'Cache-Control': null,
        'X-Requested-With': null
    },
    filesizeBase: 1024,
    maxFilesize: 102400, // 100G in MB, max onedrive filesize
    chunking: true,
    chunkSize: CHUNK_SIZE,
    params: function(files, xhr, chunk) {
        if (chunk) {
            const chunk_start = (chunk.index * CHUNK_SIZE)
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', 
                'bytes ' + chunk_start
                + '-' + (chunk_start + chunk.dataBlock.data.size - 1) 
                + '/' + files[0].size)
            var _send = xhr.send
            xhr.send = function() {
                _send.call(xhr, chunk.dataBlock.data)
            }
        } else {
            var _send = xhr.send
            xhr.send = function() {
                _send.call(xhr, files[0])
            }
        }
    }
}
```